# TypeError: объект 'str' нельзя интерпретировать как целое число

Tags: python-3.x

Я не понимаю , как можно сделать эту программу.Пользователь должен ввести число, а цикл for должен вывести это число в виде слова "Hello!". Я просто не понимаю , как должно это работать. Вот код:

```
User = input('Введите число: ')
for User in range('Hello!'):
    print(User)
```

Я пробовал конвертировать переменные,не помогло.

Comment: Что такое «число в виде слова»?

Comment: Получите от пользователя число на вводе и используйте цикл for для вывода на экран текста 'Hello!' столько же раз

Comment: `for _ in range(int(input())): print('Hello!')`

Comment: Судя по коду, вам необходимо вернуться к самому началу учебника и начинать разбираться по новой.